# Debugging node.js ES6 code with VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js

I followed this manual:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vscode/2015/07/06/visual-studio-code-es6/

And added this to my `jsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=759670
    // for the documentation about the jsconfig.json format
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "files": [
        "app.js"
    ]
}
```

When adding to app.js:

```
let myVar;
```

I'm getting a syntax error:

```
let myVar;
    ^^^^^
```

If I change `let` to `var` - it's all good.
What is wrong?
I believe it's related to the way VSCode runs node:

```
node --debug-brk=30696 --nolazy bin/www 
debugger listening on port 30696
```

Comment: To be clear, are you getting an error when you try to debug in node or are you simply seeing a syntax error being show in the editor.  If the latter, what does the editor say when you mouse over the error?  If the former, when you run your node app outside of VSCode, do you see the same error?

Comment: @ChrisScott same when running node app.js

Comment: if it's the same in node, then it's likely unrelated to VS Code.  Have you tried adding "use strict"; to the top of your js file?  Also, if you go into the node repl, and try to declare a let variable, do you see the same error?

Comment: 'use strict' didn't solve this issue.
when using repl i'm getting 3 dots: "..."

Comment: Curious.  What version of node are you using?  And when you are entering the repl, it's `> node` without any arguments?  And when you type `> let myVar = "Hello World!";` you get the ellipsis?

Comment: @ChrisScott v0.10.25.
still getting those 3 dots "..."

Comment: @ChrisScott upgraded now to v4.4.7 - same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by upgrading node + adding harmony arg to `.vscode\launch.json` :

```
"runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy",
        "--harmony"
            ],
```

Comment: Odd that adding the `--harmony` flag in node 4.4.7 worked.  `let` declarations have been support by default for a few releases as per http://node.green/

Answer (score 1):

The correct file extension is jsconfig.**json** and in target place **ES6**.

Comment: sorry. that is my file. just a typo in the question